# How to make ctrl word end or start recognize underscore

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> will not stop at an underscore. Is there any way to change this behaviour, or is there a shortcut to select characters between two underscores?

(I have searched through available shortcuts and extensions but could not find any)

Thanks!

Comment: If you are just looking to get the cursor to stop at underscores when `Ctrl+left/right arrow` add the underscore character to the setting `Editor: Word Separators` list.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you add the underscore to your wordSeparators in the setting `Editor: Word Separators`, then

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> : move to the next word separator,
2. followed by another <kbd>rightArrow</kbd> to move after that `underscore`, then
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> will select all word characters up to the next word separator, which might or might not be the next `underscore` - depends on your code.

Comment: To open Settings, on Windows and Linux to go `File > Preferences > Settings` or use `Ctrl`+`,`. On macOS go to `Code > Preferences > Settings`. Then in the search box on the Settings tab, just type "word separators" to get right to the setting to add the underscore character at the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by).

With a regular expression you can specify what you recognize as a word separator. Use the `moveby.regex` command. And then redefine the key binding for `Ctrl+ArrowRight`

To select some text based on regular expressions use command `selectby.regex`:

Add to your `settings.json`

```
    "selectby.regexes": {
      "selectUnderscores": {
        "surround": "_[^_]*_"
      }
    }
```

And define a keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f10",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": ["selectUnderscores"]
  }
```